# Does support for Amazon ElastiCache for Redis exist in Spring Cloud AWS anymore?

Tags: spring-data-redis, spring-cloud-aws

We have upgraded to `io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-dependencies:3.1.0`, and I no longer see code for integration with Amazon ElastiCache for Redis as detailed in documents like [this one](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-aws/2.0.0.RELEASE/multi/multi__caching.html) and  [this one](https://reflectoring.io/spring-cloud-aws-redis/).

What is the recommended way to integrate with Amazon ElastiCache for Redis from this point forward if support is no longer built into the Spring Cloud AWS project?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws/discussions/801) discussion thread, the ElastiCache support in Spring Cloud AWS is discontinued because the built-in support for Redis in Spring Boot is good enough.